# How to move buttons to the next line in JOptionPane?

Tags: java, joptionpane

I'm quite new to Java so I started working on some basic projects.
Today I created a simple Calculator using `JOptionPane`.

In my program you first pick the type of calculation 
[image]

```
public void auswahl() 
{
    Object[] options = {"Addieren", "Subtrahieren", "Multiplizieren",
                        "Dividieren", "Potenzieren", "ABBRUCH"};
    int selected = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
                                                "Rechenart",
                                                "SimpleCalc v.1",
                    JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, 
                                                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, 
                    null, options, options[0]) + 1;

    if(selected == 1){addPane();}   
    if(selected == 2){minusPane();}
    if(selected == 3){malPane();}
    if(selected == 4){geteiltPane();}
    if(selected == 5){hochPane();}
    if(selected == 6){System.exit(0);}

}
```

Like you can see in the picture above the buttons are simply placed beside each other which makes the window pretty long especially when adding more types of calculation.

Im looking for a way to move some of the buttons to a new row below.
I saw people use `"\n"` but it doesn't work for me that way.

Comment: Use a [`GridLayout`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html). Also use an `enum` instead of an array of `Object`s.

Comment: thanks for the answere and also the redirect, i couldnt find that post for some reason, thats why i made an own post. Sorry